# .bind paste (ctrl+v) handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, bind, paste

This works great in Chrome:

```
$('body').bind({
    paste : function() {
        if(!$('input, textarea').is(':focus')) {
            alert('you used ctrl/cmd + v');
        }
    }
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work in Firefox ESR (haven't tested latest version). What adjustments need to be made?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Gx5/)**

Comment: That code means, "if the very first `<input>` or `<textarea>` tag on the page is not the current focused element, then alert ...".  Is that really what you intend? *edit* whoa shivver me timbers this is incorrect!!  mind = blown

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Updated post with a jsFiddle.

Comment: Sorry my comment was wrong - `.is()` doesn't just work on the first matched element; it's more like a `.any()` - thus if any input has focus, you won't get an alert. Firefox doesn't pay attention to paste attempts that aren't in interactive elements.